# Holding evaluation of flat, orderless, function in up value

Tags: pattern-matching, upvalues

I have an operator that is flat and orderless that I want to evaluate only after the expression has been entirely flattened.  Essentially, I want an expression of the form `f[f[x,x],x]` to only evaluate when it is in the form `f[x,x,x]`. I can accomplish this in limited cases,

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f,{Orderless,Flat,HoldAll}]
f[x__] := Length[{x}]
f[x, x, f[x, x, f[x, x], x]]
```

which evaluates correctly to 7.

However, I am stumped when I try to apply this to more complicated cases such as using UpValues.  If, for instance, I want `x x x` to evaluate as `f[x,x,x]`, which is 3, I can try

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, {Orderless, Flat, HoldAll}]
x /: y__ x := f[x, y];
x  x  x
```

which does evaluate to `f[x,x,x]` as I want.  However,

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, {Orderless, Flat, HoldAll}]
f[x__] := Length[{x}]
x /: y__ x := f[x, y];
x  x  x
```

evaluates to 2.  Is there a way to produce the desired behavior?

Is there any way to obtain the desired behavior?

**Edit:**
I have found the solution to the problem thanks to jjc385, I forgot to clear up values associated with `x`.  I used something like

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, {Orderless, Flat, HoldAll}]
f[x__] := Length[{x}]
x /: y_ x := f[x, y];
x  x  x
```

before which does indeed evaluate to 2, and never cleared `x` before trying the version I posted.

Comment: What `$Version` are you using?  For me (`11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)`), your last line evaluates to 3.

Comment: @jjc385 Thank you, I found the error.  I had an up value associated with `x` that I did not know about, thanks to typos in my original code.  Clearing `x` produces the desired response.